# iphone+hide tabbar when any view is pushed

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am designing an app which has more than 4 options in tabbar,So all i want to do is to hide the tabbar when any view is being pushed and show it again when view is popped,I tried the hidesbottomwhenpushed but didn't work for me.Please help

Comment: Can you pl. show the code how you have done that?

Comment: Actually,what i have done is that i have selected tabbarcontrollers option "Hides bottom when pushed" through xib.Is there something i am missing.

Answer (score 1):

use this function

```
- (void) hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller 
{
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
        {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
            } 
            else 
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
            }

        }

        [UIView commitAnimations];

 }
```

when you are call this function

```
[self hideTabBar:self. tabbarcontroller];
```

when you want to show the tabbarcontroller use this function

```
 - (void) showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", view);

            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
            {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];

        } 
        else 
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 431)];
        }


    }

    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

Comment: Very useful! I have a question on it: can't he just hide the UITabBar view instead of changing its frame?

Comment: are you use tab bar in app delegete?

Comment: please use the present model view controller (simple way)